# Tem como debugar Java no Eclipse, excluindo classes/pacotes

Tags: eclipse, jar, debug

Minha aplicação usa JSF/Hibernate, e uma série de outro complementos (jar).

Quando tenho de *debugar*, uma página, ele para no *breakpoint* e depois de alguns `Steps` (debug) ele cai dentro do `jar` do JSF.

Tem como informar para o Eclipse que os `Steps` é só para a minha aplicação, excluindo todos os outros jar/libs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem sim, são chamados [Step Filters](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-usestepfilters.htm).

Você pode acessar as configurações em:

```
Java > Debug > Step Filtering
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O botão [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
(`Shift+F5`) habilita / desabilita os filtros (na perspectiva *Debug*).